# How to remove a file named .css from all branches in git

Tags: git, git-branch

I am working with a git repository that somehow has a file named `.css` in it. This causes an error when checking out in Windows (but in Linux it works fine).

How do I remove this file from all branches in *git*, *without* accidentally *removing* all css files from all branches?

Comment: Do you want to rewrite all commits in the history of the project, or just the most recent commit in all branches? I'm assuming you're gonna try doing it on a Linux machine

Comment: Ideally the most recent commit on all branches, so that if someone tries to checkout any branch in windows they will be able to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I remove this file from all branches in git, without accidentally removing all css files from all branches?

[Omer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63234798/1256452) shows one way; here is another.

Note: you aren't *removing the file from branches*.  You are making *new commits that lack the file*, which each new commit made on some particular branch.  This is an important distinction because the existing commits continue to exist, and continue to have the file.  No existing commit can ever be altered!  You simply stop *using* those commits.  But as long as you still have those earlier commits, any attempt to extract one of them on Windows will give you the same sort of heartburn.<sup>1</sup>

To make a new commit on a branch, we will (of course) use `git commit` as usual.  To *get* on some particular branch, we will use `git checkout` or `git switch` as usual.  As in Omer's answer, it's important to be sure that you are starting from a clean setup, though I won't show any particular method for guaranteeing that here.

Given a list of branches that do have the file whose name is literally `*.css`, we now want a loop, written in whatever scripting language you prefer.  Since Git includes sh (or bash) and that's a nice powerful scripting language, that's the one I would use here:

```
for name in br1 br2 br3 master; do
    git checkout $name &&
    git rm -f -- ":(literal)*.css" &&
    git commit -m "remove file named *.css" ||
    echo "failed to update branch $name"
done
```

The `:(literal)` prefix is part of a *pathspec* and prevents `git rm` from expanding `*.css` to match all the `.css` files.  This is documented in [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary), albeit rather well-hidden.  (The `-f` flag here allows the `git rm` even on Windows, though on Windows the `git checkout` step would probably fail so you'd have to modify the `&&` chain.  If you are doing this on a Linux system you don't need the `-f` flag here.)

You can follow this up with a single `git push` of all the branches in question:

```
git push origin br1 br2 br3 master
```

for instance.

---

<sup>1</sup>It *is* possible to "rewrite history" in a Git repository so as to not merely stop *using* a commit, but also stop keeping it in the repository at all.  The downside to doing this is that every *subsequent* commit's commit-number (hash-ID) also changes, such that the new repository can never be mixed with the original repository: if it is mixed together, all the old commits come right back.  This is sometimes, but not all that often, worth the pain it takes to achieve.  The amount of pain depends on the number and importance of copies of the repository that exist and have the original commits, pre-rewrite.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you can do it for a single branch, since "all branches" is rather ambiguous, I left the automation/iteration part over all branches for you to do how you prefer (I suggest doing it manually if you don't have too many branches that have this problematic file)

```
# First checkout the branch - WARNING - Note I use
# --force here to make sure `git status` is clean. 
# I'm relying on it later when doing `git add -A`.
# The --force flag will delete any uncommited local changes,
# so make sure you don't have any of those before running
# the following command
git checkout --force my_branch

# Now delete the `*.css` file. Note the single quotes, they
# are crucial to prevent the shell from doing expansion on the asterisk:
rm -- '*.css'

# Add "all" the changes (The deletion of the file should be the only change):
git add -A

# Now commit
git commit -m 'Removed evil *.css file'

# And push
git push origin my_branch
```

I didn't use `git rm` (which combines deletion and `git add` in one command) on purpose because I couldn't get it to ignore the `*` as a character, it tried to get smart and delete all `.css` files in the project. EDIT: See [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63235227/791430) for a way to specify literal asterisks in git commands

Comment: Yes, (?) `git rm` and other Git commands do their own glob expansion of pathspecs. There is a way around this though (well, multiple ways, you showed one here!) :-)

Comment: (Oops, I forgot to delete the `(?)` above when I deleted the word "unfortunately" -- sometimes it's fortunate, sometimes not, and this was a "not" case.)